# How to use Assert method and Selenium with TestNg framework to compare two integers

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion

I am practicing Selenium using the TestNG framework and assertion and there are 3 things that I can't solve.
note: there is no page for XPath.. integers are static.

1. selenium script to Compare 3 and 5.
2. selenium script to get boolean result of 3>5.
3. Selenium script for a string to check palindrom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/latest/org/testng/Assert.html

see the full list of support assertion , so there is no specific method for checking greater than, use equals and true.

```
import org.testng.Assert;

Assert.assertEquals(2, 2);
Assert.assertFalse( 2 > 30 , "comparing 2 greater than 30");
Assert.assertEquals("teet", new StringBuilder("teet").reverse().toString());

Assert.assertTrue("teet".contentEquals(new StringBuilder("teet").reverse().toString())
```

Comment: I am not getting any console output for compare and palindrom.

Comment: @vinayajmera the output will be printed only for failures not for pass

Answer (score 1):

you can do this :

```
Assert.assertTrue(number1 > number2 ,"if condition is false this message will be written");
```

Here we need to assert that number is greater than number 2, eaaasy !